# No se llama al viewdidappear() de mi controlador cuando lo uso en el tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando vengo de un shortcut 3d, forzar al tab bar controller a que elija un index.

Si hago esto en el `viewdidAppear()` del tab bar controller, el problema es que el `viewDidAppear()` de mi controlador principal embedido no se llama. Si vuelvo a clicar sobre el tab bar item entonces ya sí que se llama.

Con el resto de controladores no pasa. Entiendo porque no es el que primero está en la lista de items del tab bar controller.

Tab bar controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if goTasks {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    } else if goTodo {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
    } else if goProjects {
        self.selectedIndex = 3
    } else if goSearch {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }

}
```

Mi viewcontroller de índice 0.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(isSearchingServer)
}
```

Si hago debug puedo ver que no llega a entrar en este último `viewdidAppear()`.
¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución y esta en hacer la llamada al super.viewDidAppear()

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if goTasks {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    } else if goTodo {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
    } else if goProjects {
        self.selectedIndex = 3
    } else if goSearch {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
```